# Socket communication

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, redis, socket.io

I have the amazon ami server, through this i want to achieve socket communication by using nodejs, redis server.

I follwed the below to install nodejs and redis server, npm

https://www.metachris.com/2015/10/how-to-install-nodejs-5-on-centos-and-ubuntu/

https://gist.github.com/dstroot/2776679

Even i installed socket server and socket express also.

when i was try to know the express version this i got this error please see the attached screenshot [image]

Can anyone please suggest me what i can do to achieve socket communication in amazon ami server.

Answer (score 0):

Use node package manager commands. npm -v packagename